# How to hide multiple forms with one click in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#

I have a form named: `form1` from which I can access two other forms: `form2` and `form3`, with one click:

```
private void buttonViewEmployee_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string refNumber = 123;

    Employee employee = new Employee(refNumber);
    FormViewEmployee viewEmployee = new FormViewEmployee(employee);
    FormViewNewUpdates newUpdates = new FormViewNewUpdates(employee);

    viewEmployee.Show();
    newUpdates.Show();

    this.Hide();
}
```

Now, from `form3` I would like to hide `form2` and `form3` and go back to `form1`:

```
private void buttonBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormEditRequests editRequest = new FormEditRequests();
    FormViewEmployee viewEmp = new FormViewEmployee(null);

    viewEmp.Hide();
    this.Hide();

    editRequest.Show();
}
```

It seems to work but `form2` actually just hides itself behind `form1` but is still visible.

I tried to debug to see what happens exactly but when I debug, it works as perfect as I want but not when I am not debugging.

I tried to change the order of the code execution and also tried to use:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormViewEmployee viewEmp = new FormViewEmployee(null);
    base.OnVisibleChanged(e);
    viewEmp.Visible = false;
}
```

But didn't work either.

Can someone explains what happens during the debug mode that doesn't happen when not debugging?

Comment: Your post is a bit confusing. You mention form1, form2, form3, however, the forms that you display have different names. Nonetheless, use events. See [Handle and raise events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/) for more info.

Comment: You are creating new and completely different forms in the `buttonBack_Click` event, you need to keep references to the forms you create in the `buttonViewEmployee_Click` event. You can pass them through a parameterized ctor to `Form3`. Also, you can get the open forms through the `Application.OpenForms` collection.

Comment: If you HIDE the existing forms on "back", then are you then going to re-use those hidden forms when `buttonViewEmployee` is clicked again? As written, you are creating new forms on each click which means you'd then have a bunch of hidden instances that are "orphaned" until the application is closed. You need to learn how to PASS REFERENCES to forms...

Comment: Please don't tag a question as visual-studio when that is just the IDE that you're using. The question is not related to VS

Comment: Thank you @dr.null
It was simplier than I thought.
I just used ctor & parameters to pass the 1st created instance rather than creating a new one and that solved my issue.
Thank you for the rest of the guys. I appreciate your effort and help.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

```
public static void closeAllOpenedForms()
{
    FormCollection FM = Application.OpenForms;
    if (FM.Count > 1)
    {
        for (int i = (FM.Count); i > 1; i--)
        {
            Form sForm = Application.OpenForms[i - 1];
            sForm.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check/clone/test this code on https://github.com/JomaStackOverflowAnswers/HideForms

If you need to reuse the opened form you can hide/show as neeeded. But if you create new forms everytime is recommended to close the forms(not hide).

**FormMain**

```
namespace HideForms
{
    public partial class FormMain : Form
    {
        public FormMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void buttonOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Employee employee = new Employee("123");
            FormViewEmployee formViewEmployee = new FormViewEmployee(employee);
            FormViewNewUpdates formViewNewUpdates = new FormViewNewUpdates(employee, this, new List<Form>{ formViewEmployee });
            formViewEmployee.Show();
            formViewNewUpdates.Show();
            Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

**FormViewEmployee**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace HideForms
{
    public partial class FormViewEmployee : Form
    {
        private readonly Employee employee;

        public FormViewEmployee(Employee employee)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.employee = employee;
        }
    }
}
```

**FormViewNewUpdates**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace HideForms
{
    public partial class FormViewNewUpdates : Form
    {
        private readonly Employee employee;
        private readonly Form parent;
        private readonly List<Form> formsToClose;

        public FormViewNewUpdates(Employee employee, Form parent, List<Form> formsToClose)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.employee = employee;
            this.parent = parent;
            this.formsToClose = formsToClose;
            
        }

        private void buttonClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach(var form in formsToClose)
            {
                form.Close();//form.Hide(); //Hide in case you need to reuse the form.
            }
            Close();
            parent.Show();// Show the parent form.
        }

        private void FormViewNewUpdates_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var form in formsToClose)
            {
                form.Close();
            }
            parent.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**
***FormMain***  When click in open button, it opens FormViewEmployee, FormViewNewUpdates instances.
[image: open forms]

***FormViewEmployee, FormViewNewUpdates instances***
When click in *Close All* button it close both instances and show FormMain instance.
***2***
[image: 2]

**References**

[Control.Hide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.hide?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)
[Form.Close](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.close?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)